# Json quotes highcharts

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts, double-quotes

I have a problem with quotes result.

I'm looking at the different forums but I have not found answers.

Thank you for your help.

SQL:

```
while($r = $dataDate->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$category['data'][] = $r['maDate'];
$x = $PDO->query("SELECT COUNT(numClient) AS nb_dossier FROM psc_demandes WHERE DATE_FORMAT( dateDemande, '%Y-%m-%d' ) = '".$r['maDate']."' AND idSite = 1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$series1['data'][] = $x['nb_dossier'];
$y = $PDO->query("SELECT COUNT(numClient) AS nb_dossier FROM psc_demandes WHERE DATE_FORMAT( dateDemande, '%Y-%m-%d' ) = '".$r['maDate']."' AND idSite = 2")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$series2['data'][] = $y['nb_dossier'];}
$result = array();
array_push($result,$category);
array_push($result,$series1);
array_push($result,$series2);

print json_encode($result);
```

HTML:

```
        $.getJSON("ajax/graphAccueil.php", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            options.series[1] = json[2];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
```

JSON result :

```
[{"name":"Jours","data":["2013-12-09","2013-12-10","2013-12-11"]},{"name":"Michel","data":["0","5","3"]},{"name":"Tony","data":["1","2","1"]}]
```

Just data of days and names works, but no résults.

EDIT:

Finaly th solution is (using int()) :

```
while($r = $dataDate->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $category['data'][] = frenchDate($r['maDate']);
    $dataX = $PDO->query("SELECT COUNT(numClient) AS nb_dossier FROM psc_demandes WHERE DATE_FORMAT( dateDemande, '%Y-%m-%d' ) = '".$r['maDate']."' AND idSite = 1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $series1['data'][] = (int)$dataX['nb_dossier'];
    $dataY = $PDO->query("SELECT COUNT(numClient) AS nb_dossier FROM psc_demandes WHERE DATE_FORMAT( dateDemande, '%Y-%m-%d' ) = '".$r['maDate']."' AND idSite = 2")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $series2['data'][] = (int)$dataY['nb_dossier']; 
}
```

Comment: Could you attach example of your `json` variable from getJSON ?

Answer (score 1):

In data array you need to use y values or pairs x,y, which are number, not string. Dates should be timestamps (time in miliseconds). You can use loop and parse/transform your json to correct form and then use in highcharts.

Answer (score 1):

I think its an issue with Highcharts. When your data is enclosed in quotes that point wont render. Take a look at the Tokyo dataset where I have added quotes around the first value

http://jsfiddle.net/j8sze/

```
 series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: ["7.0", 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
```